# Selecting columns of a data.table using a vector of column names or column positions without using "with = F"

Tags: r, performance, indexing, data.table

I need to select specific columns of a `data.table` with a vector of column names or positions.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(cbind(A=rnorm(50),B=rnorm(50),C=rnorm(50),D=rnorm(50)))
```

Indexing column's "A" and "C" works well this way.

```
DT[,c("A","C")]
```

but if i specify a variable and try to index it fails.

```
mycols <- c("A","C")
DT[,mycols]
```

I am forced to use `with=FALSE` but i dont want to, because `with=FALSE` treats DT like a `data.frame` and i loose all the performance advantages (speed) of `data.table`.

My questions are. Why does `data.table` accept a vector of characters the former way but not the latter? Is there a solution that preserves the performance advantages of `data.table`?

Thanks

Comment: FYI the `cbind()` is not needed in the first code block

Comment: That is correct, no performance difference between `..` and `with=FALSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to use double dots

```
DT[, ..mycols]
#          A           C
#1:  0.1188208 -0.17328827
#2: -0.5622505  0.84231231
#3:  0.8111072 -1.59802306
#4:  0.7968823  2.08468489
# ...
```

Or specify it in `.SDcols`

```
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = mycols]
```

or else `with = FALSE` as the OP mentioned in the post

Comment: That worked! will accept when i am able. Any insight into the first question as to why this happens?

Comment: @JustGettinStarted I guess it is a design check where it is searching for the column name 'mycols' in the data.table environment and not looking for objects outside the env i.e. on global env.  By doing the `..`, it is like `!!` in tidyverse to evaluate outside that env